# Django rest framework hide columns logic

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I have two tables (user_type and raw_data) while showing raw_data in list method user_type needs facility to hide raw_data columns(i.e. cid, eup, etc) explicitly how to do that?

Comment: Adding some more information? Like data format and commas, that will make it easier for others to help with your question

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `to_representation` method of your serializer like this

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    data = {}
    # Add data on the basis of user type in this dictionary
    return data
```

Comment: thank you !!  i have one more question can we make one more table where hide fields can save there?

Comment: You mean you want to save field which we hide before? If yes, then similar to to_representation method, you can write custom `create` method. You should see django rest serializer in detail for this. Otherwise you will stuck on each step.